# Unable to use string data type in encrypt() function of postgres

Tags: postgresql, encryption

I want to encrypt the field with string data type but as per standard definition

**encrypt(data bytea, key bytea, type text)**

As the input data type to this function is bytea, how can i use string data type in this function. I want to encrypt mobile_no columnhaving data type string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following function and it worked fine.

encrypt(cast($1 as bytea), '123', 'aes');

where $1 is the argument i passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`convert_to`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function to convert `text` into `bytea`:

I recommend using the `getdatabaseencoding()` function to get the encoding of your database and use that with `convert_to`.